# Equation of motion of a particle in a sinusoidal well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, oscillators, models

Do you have **solutions** for the (classical or not) equations of motion of a particle in a sinusoidal well or just a quartic well, classicaly I would write the equations like so:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\propto sin(x)$$
with $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$ (no periodicity) or:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\propto ax+bx^3$$
where $a$ and $b$ are some constants.

Also interested in quantum mechanical treatments.

Comment: For the quartic oscillator check “Duffing equation”.  It can only be solved approximately or numerically.

Answer (score 2):

In newtonian mechanics, you can do what's sometimes called a partial resolution. You won't get $x(t)$ analytically, but you'll get velocity as a function of position.

Multiply the differential equation by $\dot{x}$:

$$
\ddot{x}=k\sin(x)
\ddot{x}\dot{x}=-k\sin(x)\dot{x}
$$

which you can integrate as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\,\dot{x}^2=k\cos(x)+A$$

Your second example can be partially solved the same way.

You can certainly find in-depth analysis of such problems, but you won't find *analytical* solutions. Most differential equations, especially non-linear ones, don't have solutions that can be written analytically.

Comment: I think I've read that the above ODE has solutions in terms of Bessel functions.

Comment: @AfterShave It doesn't contradict my answer: it just comes down to expressing the solution in terms of functions... that you can't write analytically. It's still interesting, of course, since it can lead to a wealth of useful properties.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [exact analytic  answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)) to  equations with a $sin(x)$ in terms of elliptic functions. See the section on "arbitrary amplitude" in the link above.